# Returning Object Pointer: 'Cannot convert 'Coordinate *' to Python object'

Tags: python, c++, cython, cythonize

I'm currently trying to cythonize my c++ classes to be usabe in python and I startet with a simple class of mine, but I'm stuck with returning a pointer. My apttempt to solve this problem was to add a copy-constructor and to return the Python version of the C++ class but without any success.

I get the following error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    def bearing(self, Coordinate *coordinate):
        return self.thisptr.bearing(coordinate)

    def destination(self, double bearing, double distance):
        return PyCCoordinate(self.thisptr.destination(bearing, distance))
                                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

./coordinate.pyx:32:53: Cannot convert 'Coordinate *' to Python object
```

here are my files

**coordinate.h**

```
class Coordinate {
private:
    double m_x = 0;
    double m_y = 0;
public:
    Coordinate(const double x, const double y);

    Coordinate(const Coordinate *coord);

    void setX(const double value);

    void setY(const double value);

    double getX();

    double getY();

    double distance(Coordinate *coord);

    double bearing(Coordinate *coord);

    Coordinate *destination(const double bearing, const double distance);
};
```

**coordinate.cpp**

```
#include <cmath>
#include "coordinate.h"

Coordinate::Coordinate(const double x, const double y) {
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
}

Coordinate::Coordinate(const Coordinate *coord) {
    m_x = coord->x;
    m_y = coord->y;
}


void Coordinate::setX(const double value) {
    m_x = value;
}

void Coordinate::setY(const double value) {
    m_y = value;
}

double Coordinate::getX() {
    return m_x;
}

double Coordinate::getY() {
    return m_y;
}

double Coordinate::distance(Coordinate *coord) {
    return sqrt(pow(m_x - coord->getX(), 2.0) + pow(m_y - coord->getY(), 2.0));
}

double Coordinate::bearing(Coordinate *coord) {
    const double len_x = coord->getX() - m_x;
    const double len_y = coord->getY() - m_y;
    double res = atan2(len_y, len_x);
    if (res < 0.0) {
        res += 2.0 * M_PI;
    }
    return res;
}

Coordinate *Coordinate::destination(const double bearing, const double distance) {
    double new_x = m_x + cos(bearing) * distance;
    double new_y = m_y + sin(bearing) * distance;
    return new Coordinate(new_x, new_y);
}
```

**coordinate.pxy**

```
cdef extern from "coordinate.h":
    cdef cppclass Coordinate:
        Coordinate(const double x, const double y) except +
        Coordinate(const Coordinate *coord) except +

        void setX(const double value)
        void setY(const double value)
        double getX()
        double getY()
        double distance(Coordinate *coord)
        double bearing(Coordinate *coord)
        Coordinate *destination(const double bearing, const double distance)

cdef class PyCCoordinate:
    cdef Coordinate *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, double x, double y):
        self.thisptr = new Coordinate(x,y)
    def __cinit__(self, Coordinate* coord):
        self.thisptr = new Coordinate(coord)
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr        

    def distance(self, Coordinate *coordinate):
        return self.thisptr.distance(coordinate)

    def bearing(self, Coordinate *coordinate):
        return self.thisptr.bearing(coordinate)

    def destination(self, double bearing, double distance):
        return PyCCoordinate(self.thisptr.destination(bearing, distance))
```

Comment: Can you add a setup.py file? It's easiest for this sort of thing to create a repo on e.g. github that one of can just clone so we don't need to copy/paste files from SO. My guess is that you're missing types on an intermediate variable somewhere, but I'd need to look at the code cython generates to be sure.

Comment: this is clearly not a **minimal** example, it would make sense to reduce the amount of not really needed code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One issue, is that the cython syntax is somewhat misleading: if a `def`-function is defined as for example (because your example isn't minimal I make up an unrelated one):

```
def twice(double d):
   return 2.0*d
```

then the parameter is passed to this (python) function not as a C-double but as an usual Python-object. However, the early binding will lead to cython trying to convert this Python-object to a C-double via `__pyx_PyFloat_AsDouble` at run time as the first thing when the function is called - this all happens behind the scenes, so as coder you have this deceiving filling, you would pass really a double to the function.

However, this automatic conversion is only possible only for some types - most prominently `double`, `int`, `cdef`-classes and so on. For other types this is not possible, for example for raw pointers (that also means pointers to custom cpp-classes) - there is nothing like `__pyx_PyFloat_AsDouble`.

For example

```
def twice(double *d):
   pass
```

cannot be cythonized, because a raw pointer cannot be automatically converted from/to a python-object, which is needed for a python-function.

It would be possible to define a `cdef` function with raw-pointers because they are not more than simple C-functions, thus

```
cdef twice(double *d):
   pass
```

would compile. This however does not help you with `__cinit__`, because it must be a `def`-function.

Unluckily, Cython doesn't show all errors in your code, only the first it finds - otherwise it would show you that all your `def`s with `Coordinate *coordinate` are not valid.

How to solver it? Basically you should use your `cdef`-wrapper-class `PyCCoordinate` in signatures and then `thisptr`-for calculations, for example:

```
def distance(self, PyCCoordinate coordinate):
    return self.thisptr.distance(coordinate.thisptr)
```

This solution would obviously not work for construction of an object, like in the method `destination` - you have to construct a `PyCCoordinate`-object before you can use it! A possible solution would be to have a constructor, which would construct a wrapper-object with `thisptr` being `NULL`, call it and set this pointer manually, something like

```
cdef class PyCCoordinate:
    cdef Coordinate *thisptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr        

    def destination(self, double bearing, double distance):
        cdef PyCCoordinate res=PyCCoordinate()
        res.thisptr=self.thisptr.destination(bearing, distance)
        return res
```

Another issue: cython (but also python), unlike c++, does not know overloading, so you cannot define two different constructors (and cannot define one of them private), so the dispatch must be done manually, for example:

```
cdef class PyCCoordinate:
    cdef Coordinate *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x is None or y is None:#default, "private" constructor
           pass     #thisptr is initialized to NULL
        else:
           self.thisptr = new Coordinate(x,y) #

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr        

    def destination(self, double bearing, double distance):
        cdef PyCCoordinate res=PyCCoordinate()
        res.thisptr=self.thisptr.destination(bearing, distance)
        return res
```

Comment: Thank you very much for extensive answer. I managed to get it compiled and it does what ist should do. But for me there is to much wrapping and object construction which makes the performance gain of using cpp vanish (i guess, but haven't measured it). I have like 10 py modules which i want to implement in cpp. I planned to do this one by one, but I think its better to directly implement all modules in cpp classes and only have one small class which is the interface between py and cpp

Comment: @Westranger without knowing the code it is hard to tell, what is the bottle-neck. Normally, calling a python function has quite an overhead, so one tries to reduce the number of those calls - thus your strategy to minimize the amount of wrapped code isn't bad at all. It is easier to get efficient code in c++ than in cython (at least if your are fluent in c++ and not in cython).

Comment: I get `Deletion of non-Python, non-C++ object` when del self.thisptr

Comment: @SolomidHero in this answer `cdef cppclass Coordinate` so it is a C++-object. If you have something different (i.e. a C-pointer), use free or whatever needs to be used.